# custom js not showing on frontend until the commands are run magento 2

Tags: magento2.3.2

I am working on a magento 2 store. I have created a custom js file. It is inside

```
app/design/frontend/Napespace/Theme/web/js/custom.js
```

Now whenever I make any changes to my custom.js file, the change does not reflect on frontend until I run the following commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

I have checked my magento installation is in developer mode. Is there a way I do not have to run above commands every time, I make some changes to my custom js file as this makes the development process too slow.
I know I can write my custom js code in google console for testing but how to do it in magento so that I do not need to run these commands for every small change in js.

Answer (score 1):

yes first run this command:

- bin/magento cache:disable full_page layout block_html

Also inspect the page with your custom.js file and open the source file in new tab like this:

[image]

once you make changes to the js file, simply reload the page you opened in the "source tab" as the gif explains

Cheers

Comment: Could you also plz tell me a way for loading custom.css file without running commands. css is present inside custom theme web directory